# What should be the values for the Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: jmeter

If I want to extract the value for access token what should be the values for the below in Regular Expression Extractor

```
{"access_token":"YaTtnlYnqSuXIZ9K1BouYC3jgxjVQV6qpAyCnkv6","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":28800,"refresh_token":"FkpJDh8c6x4xOp0o3GPb28kfSLVTPCZNCCiSSUZ4"},
```

Reference name: ? 
Regular Expression: ? 
Template: ? 
Match No: ? 
DefaultValue: ?

Comment: Hi, you can also upvote answer :-) thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression will be `"access_token":"(\w+)"` to extract the value for access token. See [here](https://regex101.com/) to match the expression.

```
Reference name: Any_Variable_like_i.e_Var1
Regular Expression: "access_token":"(\w+)"
Template: $1$
Match No: 1
DefaultValue: No need to put any value there.
```

You can set your regular expression extractor like this:
[image]

Comment: I would suggest to fill in the 'default value' field to something like NOT_FOUND. So each time the extraction fails you know it.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

> $..access_token for access_token
>
> $..refresh_token for refresh_token

See:

[image]